# Can i read file properties from unmanged .dll or .exe in .NET

Tags: c#, reflection

How can i read file informations like title, description, copyright etc from unmanaged dlls and exe, written in c++, with C#?

I know how to get these informations from managed code with `MetadataLoadContext`, but loading an C++ Exe/DLL will throw an exception: `System.BadImageFormatException: This PE image is not a managed executable`.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo` instead of reflection.